# Adjoint of a functional

Tags: functional-analysis

Problem: Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be a normed space. Consider $f$ in $\mathfrak{X}^\ast$ as a linear bounded operator in $\textbf{B}(\mathfrak{X}, \mathbb{F})$. Compute $f^\ast$ in $\textbf{B}(\mathbb{F}, \mathfrak{X}^\ast)$.

My thoughts: We need to find $f^\ast:\mathbb{F}\rightarrow\mathfrak{X}$ that satisfies $\langle x, f^\ast y \rangle =\langle fx,y \rangle$. $f$ is a functional since it maps to $\mathbb{F}$. It's easy to compute the value of $||f^\ast||$ from its relation with $||f||$ from the properties of linearly bounded operators:

$$||T^\ast y|| = \sup\{|\langle Tx, y\rangle | : x\in X, ||x||\leq 1\}$$

From this we can also show that $f^\ast \in \textbf{B}(\mathbb{F}, \mathfrak{X}^\ast)$. However, I'm stuck on how to actually compute the adjoint itself.

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ and $W$ are two normed spaces, then the adjoint of $T \in \mathcal{B}(V,W)$ is the map $T^* \in \mathcal{B}(W^*,V^*)$ given by $$T^*(g) = g \circ T$$ for all $g \in W^*$.

So, if $f \in \mathcal{B}(X,\mathbb{F})$, then $f^* \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{F}^*,X^*)$. But as $\mathbb{F}^* \cong \mathbb{F}$, we could view $f^*$ as an element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{F},X^*)$.

More precisely, since the isomorphism $\mathbb{F}^* \cong \mathbb{F}$ follows by identifying $a \in \mathbb{F}$ with  the functional $\hat{a} \in \mathbb{F}^*$ given by $\hat{a}(x) = ax$ for all $x \in \mathbb{F}$, the element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{F},X^*)$ associated to $f^*$ maps $a \in \mathbb{F}$ to
$$
f^*(\hat{a}) = \hat{a} \circ f = af.
$$